# INSERT from VIEW get stuck on ORACLE DB

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I have an issue which I can't figure it out why is happening.

I try to insert data from a view `V_NAME` into a table `T_NAME`.

```
INSERT INTO t_name SELECT * FROM v_name;
```

But this is taking very very long time... and I must manually interrupt it. (more than 7h). The view contains 1068021 rows. The table structure is identical with the view structure.

I tried to run this:

```
INSERT INTO t_name SELECT * from v_name where rownum < 2;
```

But I have the same situation.

I've also tried to create a tmp_name table as `SELECT * FROM v_name where rownum < 1;` (to be empty) and then I tried the INSERT, but I got the same thing.

Can you please tell me why this is happening? Nothing has changed, and the data is ok, from what I can tell.

Comment: Can you select from the view reasonably fast?

Comment: how long take `SELECT * FROM v_name` ?

Comment: Can you get an execution plan for this statement? Do you have an open transaction on the target table? Oracle version? Does the view run without the insert?

Comment: The explain plain return 1 min TIME to run. And I can insert into the table bulk data INSERT into t_name values('1','2',3,4)...

Comment: How long it takes when you do select from view and pull all results not just first rows?

Comment: I did run it now, and it takes aprox. 5 minutes. More or less.

Comment: Please attach the execution plans with and without the insert